# String parsing - Java

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to java so please go easy on me!

I have created a window, pane, label, text field etc.

What is the simplest code to see what the user has inputted into the text field (as a String), as I know for a float you can use `Float.parseFloat(txtName.getText());`?

Comment: This question is extremely vague and needs more clarification to be answered properly.

Comment: Dunno why this got so many downvotes, esp. without comments. I'm sure other people must have asked the same thing. Anyway, your approach is the correct one, but be sure to surround with try/catch in case the user hasn't entered a valid floating-point number.

Comment: I found your answer helpful, but Edward Falk's answer had more relevance to the programme I was writing!

Comment: Maybe if you had clarified your question, I would be able to write a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: if you want to really do it right, you can implement a subclass of JTextField that doesn't even let the user enter characters that are invalid floating-point numbers:

```
public class FloatField extends JTextField {

    public FloatField(int cols) {
        super(cols)
    } 

    protected Document createDefaultModel() { 
        return new FloatDocument();
    } 

    static class FloatDocument extends PlainDocument {

        public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a)
                          throws BadLocationException { 
            if( str == null ) 
                return;

            // Reject any string with invalid float characters.
            // TODO: this could be more sophisticated
            int len = str.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                char c = str.charAt(i);
                if (c != '.' && c != '-' && !Character.isDigit(c))
                    return;
            }
            super.insertString(offs, str, a);
        } 
    } 
}
```

Note: this is an imperfect implementation for illustration purposes only, there are still many invalid floating-point numbers that this would allow to leak through.

Answer (score 1):

For my understanding of the question, here is a simple example of outputting something entered in a `JTextField` and appending it to a `JTextArea`:

[image]

```
public class Test {
    private static String ENTER = "Enter";
    static JButton enterButton;
    public static JTextArea output;
    public static JTextField input;
    static JFrame frame;
    static JPanel panel;

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        createFrame();
    }

    public static void createFrame()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener();
        output = new JTextArea(15, 50);
        output.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        output.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(output);
        scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        JPanel inputpanel = new JPanel();
        inputpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        input = new JTextField(20);
        enterButton = new JButton("Enter");
        enterButton.setActionCommand(ENTER);
        enterButton.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        input.setActionCommand(ENTER);
        input.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) output.getCaret();
        caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
        panel.add(scroller);
        inputpanel.add(input);
        inputpanel.add(enterButton);
        panel.add(inputpanel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        // Center of screen
        // frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        input.requestFocus();
    }

    public static class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {

        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent ev)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread()
            {

                public void run()
                {
                    if (!input.getText().trim().equals(""))
                    {
                        String cmd = ev.getActionCommand();
                        if (ENTER.equals(cmd))
                        {
                            output.append(input.getText() + "\n");
                        }
                    }
                    input.setText("");
                    input.requestFocus();
                }
            };
            thread.start();
        }
    }
}
```